# Cannot access tkcalendar output as results

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to get the selected date from `tkcalendar` and save it in a text file, but it seems that is not possible.
Here is the function:

````py
def datepicked():

            tkc = Calendar(root,selectmode = "day",year=2022,month=1,date=1)
            #display on main window
            tkc.pack(pady=90)
            def fetch_date():
                date.config(text = "You selected: " + tkc.get_date())
                newdate=tkc.get_date
                return newdate

            #add button to load the date clicked on calendar
            but = Button(root,text="Select Date",command=fetch_date, bg="black", fg='white')
            #displaying button on the main display
            but.pack()
            but.place(x=500, y=200)
            #Label for showing date on main display
            date = Label(root,text="",bg='black',fg='white')
            date.pack(pady=10)
            date.place(x=480, y=250)```
````

Is there a way I can have the date saved as a variable and use it in another function which I called `datepicked`?

Comment: You're saving the selected date in a *local variable*, that ceases to exist once the Button's function exits.  (And `return`ing the value is utterly pointless, nothing will ever see that value).  You could use a global variable - but the normal approach is to do everything you need to do with the value inside that function.